# angular - get image from api

Tags: angular, image, api

I am doing a small project using angular and swagger for the api.. I have some boats with some information stored in swagged as shown below:

```
"draft": 6.5,
"length": 2.3,
"dateFrom": "11/10/2020",
"dateTo": "21/10/2020",
"departingCity": "Amalfi Coast",
"offerPrice": 9416.6,
"discount": 0.3,
"hasWifi": true,
"hasGps": true,
"offerType": "BAREBOAT",
"boatImages": [
  {
    "id": "d4cb7afd-f677-4a5d-b2a5-cad5b1489d25",
    "filename": "CMTW-80722.png"
  }
]
```

Then, in angularjs I create an object boat and store each instance inside it.. Then, I show each boat using an ngFor to display each boat inside the list, as shown below:

```
<div class="card mb-4 bg-secondary" *ngFor="let boat of this.boatList">
.
.
.
<p class="card-text">Number of cabins: {{boat.numberOfCabins}}</p>
<p class="card-text">Number of Berths: {{boat.numberOfBerths}}</p>
```

The only problem is that I must display the boat image.. And I am thinking that I should display it using the filename that is shown above.. However, I cannot seem to get the file name.. I tried `{{boat.boatImages.filename}}`, `{{boat.boatImages[1]}}`, and `{{boat.boatImages[filename]}}` but neither worked... would be nice to get an answer! Thanks!

Comment: angularjs !== Angular.  `numberOfCabins` is not in your supplied dataset.  Assuming it's just incomplete here it should be `boat.boatImages[0].filename` but it's difficult to tell based on what you've supplied here.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply.. I tried {{boat.boatImages[0].filename}} and I managed to get the filename (paie.jpg), however, when I tried to display the image in an img tag as follows, <img src="http://localhost:8080/boat-offer/{{boat.boatImages[0].filename}}">, it gave me a broken image..Am I displaying the image wrong?

Comment: Use `<img [src]=...` instead of `<img src=...`